# Using Font Awesome to display arrow in button div

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm trying to use Font Awesome to create an arrow that will sit on the right of my text in a button (`div`).

However, the arrow isn't displaying. I'm unsure on whether it's a error in my `@font-face` or an error in the way I've implemented the font.

```css
.formLink {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 88px;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
  width: 250px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #e82171, #ef3e36);
  padding: 24px 1.2em;
  border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'GeomanistRegular', sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="formLink">Download now <i class="fas fa-arrow-right" style="font-family: 'FontAwesome';"></i></div>
```

The [style of arrow I'm trying to use](https://fontawesome.com/icons/arrow-right?style=solid).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

To use the Font Awesome icons, add the following line(CDN) inside the `<head></head>` section of your HTML page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  src: url(https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/548247/Tomorrow%20People/Landing%20Page/Template%20Build/fa-regular-400.svg) format("svg");
}

.formLink {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 88px;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
  width: 250px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #e82171, #ef3e36);
  padding: 24px 1.2em;
  border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'GeomanistRegular', sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="formLink">Download now <i class="fas fa-arrow-right" style="font-family: 'FontAwesome';"></i></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use font-awesome css file or CDN.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

```css
.formLink {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 88px;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
  width: 250px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #e82171, #ef3e36);
  padding: 24px 1.2em;
  border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'GeomanistRegular', sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="formLink">Download now <span class="fa fa-arrow-right" ></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer Below Fiddle

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j14duqo6/3/)

You can import Font Awesome File using CSS.

```
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="formLink">Download now <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></div>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"); /* FA CSS import */

.formLink {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 88px;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
  width: 250px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #e82171, #ef3e36);
  padding: 24px 1.2em;
  border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'GeomanistRegular', sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something you could do is use a `link` attribute in your html head file, like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

This should allow you to use the arrow you want `<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>` if not try using `<i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>`